# How to change border title on button click?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to build a GUI interface. I have made wrapper panel which has the title "Staff Details" as in the screenshot below:

[image: output]

I used the following code to set the title on the border

```
wrapper.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(), "Staff Details",TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.TOP));
```

Now I want to change the title to "View Details" when I click the "View" button. How do I do that?

Comment: ..call `wrapper.setBorder(..)` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably keep the `TitledBorder` reference

```
TitledBorder titledBorder = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(...);
```

Then you should be able to just `setTitle()`

```
titledBorder.setTitle("New Title");
repaint();
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `button` with the actual name of your View Details Button

```
  button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //Execute stuff when button is pressed

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
panel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Your Title", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.CENTER, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Font", 0, 18)));
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.