# Make a TitledBorder title editable

Tags: java, swing, titled-border

Is there a way to make the title in TitledBorder editable so the user can edit what the title is? Or if there's another border that may allow this, what is it?

```
Box.setBorder(new TitledBorder(editableString));
```

**EDIT:**

Here's a link to my more specific question of editing based on a double click: 
[Make TitledBorder editable upon double click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51426288/make-titledborder-editable-upon-double-click)

Comment: See if this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29304680/how-to-change-border-title-on-button-click

Comment: Border is not a component, so it cannot get focus, and therefore cannot be directly edited by the user. It's possible to do something which looks like thing what you want, but it's not so easy.

Comment: Do I have to extend the TitledBorder class and make it so it excepts a JTextBox as a title? Is that possible?

Comment: No. As I already said, Border is not a component. and cannot get focus.

Comment: If all else fails, I'll create an extra box on top of my current box then set the current boxes border, but I like the design of the TitledBorder more.

Comment: Try to override onMouseClicked listener on the JPanel and check the coordinates if it is at the title and open an JOptionPane to ask a new title. Using a EditText at the position would be another solution but you had to draw all borders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, keep a reference to the titled border, change it when needed, then repaint the component with the border. As below: change the text in the text field then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to see the effect.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class EditableTitledBorder {

    private JComponent ui = null;
    private TitledBorder titledBorder;

    EditableTitledBorder() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui!=null) return;

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4,4));
        String initialTitle = "Dark Image";
        titledBorder = new TitledBorder(initialTitle);
        ui.setBorder(titledBorder);
        final JTextField titleField = new JTextField(initialTitle);
        ActionListener changeTitleListener = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                titledBorder.setTitle(titleField.getText());
                ui.repaint();
            }
        };
        titleField.addActionListener(changeTitleListener);
        ui.add(titleField, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        ui.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(
                new BufferedImage(200,40,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB))));
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                EditableTitledBorder o = new EditableTitledBorder();

                JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want the title itself to be clickable and changed. I don't really like the look of two titles. Even if that means right clicking or double clicking the Border to open a TextField that changes the border. I'm also using a BoxLayout and Boxes instead. Thank you though.

Comment: *"I want the title itself to be clickable and changed."* O..K I suggest you mark this question as answered and ask a new, more specific question that gives the extra requirement.

Comment: Will do. My fault for not being specific enough in the question.